# Flutter Google Maps - Rotate marker according to the driving direction

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-maps-markers, map-directions

Can anyone share a documentation / code sample for Flutter google maps plugin where I can rotate the marker ( ex: a car icon ) according to the driving direction. I saw this can be achieved on native library by rotating the marker. But couldn't fjnd any option to rotate the marker in Flutter.

I guess we need to consider below points while rotating the marker. Please add your thoughts on this as well.

Map North Direction.
Devices rotation from compass.

Thanks

Comment: Have you resolved that issue? Please help me if can fix this.

Comment: @Buddhika Do you find solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://pub.dev/packages/location plugin :

Marker(
  rotation: currentLocation.heading
  )

Comment: why does my heading keeps changing continuously??

I/flutter ( 7082): cur: 214.064697265625
I/flutter ( 7082): cur: 189.31724548339844

I am not rotating my phone whats so ever

Comment: what is current Location? please describe and share proper answer, please

Comment: @SagarRAnghan                                                                                                                                         

From Location plugin :                                                                                                                                  

Location location = Location();
final currentLocation= await location.getLocation();

Answer (score 1):

you can add compass plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_compass and simply set the result direction to marker

Comment: flutter_compass is working for this solution. but this plugin not support for all devices. example: Huawei, Xiaomi

Comment: @BloodLoss  there is another solution, please use location plugin https://pub.dev/packages/location plugin, which will give you the heading direction

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the rotation angle between two `LatLng` points to rotate the `Marker` using some mathematics. The below code is generated using an AI tool, and it works perfectly. Here, `startPoint` is the user's current location, and `endPoint` is the position where the user will move, and we have to show a direction arrow from `start` to `end` point.

```
double calculateBearing(LatLng startPoint, LatLng endPoint) {
    final double startLat = toRadians(startPoint.latitude);
    final double startLng = toRadians(startPoint.longitude);
    final double endLat = toRadians(endPoint.latitude);
    final double endLng = toRadians(endPoint.longitude);

    final double deltaLng = endLng - startLng;

    final double y = Math.sin(deltaLng) * Math.cos(endLat);
    final double x = Math.cos(startLat) * Math.sin(endLat) -
        Math.sin(startLat) * Math.cos(endLat) * Math.cos(deltaLng);

    final double bearing = Math.atan2(y, x);

    return (toDegrees(bearing) + 360) % 360;
  }

  double toRadians(double degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.pi / 180.0);
  }

  double toDegrees(double radians) {
    return radians * (180.0 / Math.pi);
  }
```

Then, you can use this to rotate the `Marker` like this:

```
Marker(
   markerId: MarkerId(currentPosition.toString()),
   position: currentPosition,
   icon: movementArrow,  // Custom arrow Marker
   // Rotate the arrow in direction of movement. Func is defined below
   rotation: calculateBearing(previousPosition, currentPosition) - 90, 
   anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5), 
);
```

Here is a demo image:

[image: demo_direction]