# How to change the orientation of the map of google maps in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I'm drawing polyline in google maps with flutter, but the destination goes in the opposite direction, I need it to appear like the image

I have the map as the first image that I attach

https://ibb.co/pdXtbVB

I need the map like the second image

https://ibb.co/bvzypBW

Comment: Did you try CameraPosition - bearing ?

Comment: Looks like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964500/flutter-google-maps-rotate-marker-according-to-the-driving-direction) is the one you're looking for.